# Angular ReplaySubject getting duplicate or stale values

Tags: angular, observable

Im having an issue with my observables, I have a dropdown list with values coming from the back end
I have other component that can add or delete values that should be reflected in that dropdown list.
Whenever i add a value than on the dropdown list i see double values, and worse still when i delete a value, its still on the dropdown list

As the title suggests im using ReplaySubject as follows

SERVICE

```
  editDeleteCategoryEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  editDelteManufacturerEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  categories$: Subject<any[]> = new ReplaySubject<any[]>(1);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private global: GlobalUrlService) {
    this.getCategories();
  }

  getCategories() {
    this.http.get<any[]>(this.global.getProductCategoryUrl())
      .subscribe(
      categories => this.categories$.next(categories),
      error => this.categories$.error(error)
      );
  }

  subscribeToCategories(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.categories$;
  }
```

The component where i initilize the dropdown list

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

import { ProductConfigService } from '../../../../services/product-config.service';
import { Message } from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-product',
  templateUrl: './add-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-product.component.css']
})
export class AddProductComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private productService: ProductConfigService) {
        productService.addProductEvent.subscribe(() => this.display = true);
        productService.editDeleteCategoryEvent.subscribe(() => this.getCategories());
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.getCategories();
      }

      clearForm() {
        this.form.reset();
      }

      getCategories() {

        this.productCategories = [];
        this.productCategories.push({ label: 'Product Category', value: null });
        this.productService.subscribeToCategories().subscribe(categories => {
          categories.map(category => {
    // since the subscriber gives me double values, i added the hack but on delete its not working, and moreover it should bring double values
                if (!this.productCategories.find(x =>  x.label === category.categoryName)) {
                  this.productCategories.push({ label: category.categoryName, value: category.categoryName });
                }
              });
            });
          }
```

The component where I add add or delete a category:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductConfigService } from '../../../services/product-config.service';
import { ConfirmationService, Message } from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-setting',
  templateUrl: './product-setting.component.html',
  providers: [ConfirmationService],
  styleUrls: ['./product-setting.component.css']
})
export class ProductSettingComponent implements OnInit {

  productTypes = [];

  products = [];

  msgs: Message[] = [];

  // holds the product categories
  categories = [];

  constructor(private productService: ProductConfigService,
    private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) { }
    addCategory(category) {
        this.msgs = [];
        this.productService.addCategory({ categoryName: category }).subscribe(
          sucess => {
            this.categories = [];
            this.msgs.push({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Success', detail: 'Added the category: ' + category });
    // bring the newly categories list from the back end with the thought that subscribers should be refreshed
            this.productService.getCategories();
    // notify the previous component to resubsribe
            this.productService.editDeleteCategoryEvent.emit();
          },
          error => this.msgs.push({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error Adding category', detail: error.error }));
      }
```

Comment: is it possible you are importing the 'ProductConfigService' twice ? 1. in The component where I initilize the dropdown list and 2. The component where I add add or delete a category.

Comment: @Luillyfe yes i do... each of these components is using this service

Comment: could you show us the @Component decorator in both components ?

Comment: added the missing parts of the code

Comment: @Luillyfe any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [live](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7pr8s?file=app%2Fproduct.component.ts) working example. Take a look at HttpFake Service (this is just an example how you could manage the things on the server).

**The component where you initilize the dropdown list (I think delete categories is more suitable here)**

```
getCategories() {
    this.productService.subscribeToCategories().subscribe(categories => {
        if (Array.isArray(categories)) {
            this.productCategories = categories.map(category => ({
              label: category.categoryName, value: category.categoryName }));
        } else {
            this.productCategories.push({ label: categories.categoryName, value: categories.categoryName });
        }
        console.log(this.productCategories);
    }, err => console.log(err), () => console.log('I completed too'));
}


remove(category) {
    category = { categoryName: category.label };
    this.productService.removeCategory(category)
        .subscribe(console.log); 
}
```

**The component where you add add category:**

```
addCategory(product: any) {
    const category = product.categoryName;
    this.msgs = [];
    this.productService.addCategory({ categoryName: category })
        .subscribe(sucess => {
            this.categories = [];

            this.msgs.push({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Success', detail: 'Added the category: ' + category });;
          },
        error => this.msgs.push({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error Adding category', detail: error.error }));
}
```

**Your service**

```
addCategory(category: any): Observable<any> { 
  return this.http.post(`htps://url/categories`, category)
     .pipe(
         tap(data => this.categories.next(data))
     );
}

removeCategory(category: any) {
   return this.http.delete(`htps://url/categories`, category)
      .pipe(
          tap(data => this.getCategories())
      );
}
```

Comment: on the service can you explain a bit, i usually just return the http.delete which is an observable, what is the pipe and tap?

Comment: It is just the new sugar syntactic for 5.5. Tap is a replacement for Do (Transparently perform actions or side-effects, such as logging), Take a glance to https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md